# What can cause this slow load pattern - Firebug

Tags: performance, browser, firebug

We are eventually going to use CDN but currently all files are loaded from the same domain as the main site.

I am perplexed to see close to 15 secs of blocked time. The site loads reasonably fast at my end but at the client's environment it takes 30 sec for the first time load.

All optimization for loading has been implemented (gzip, expiry...etc) and the site ranks 95 in gtmetrix.

Any suggestions as to why this might be happening at the clients computer ?

[image: Firebug]

Comment: looks like css and js are also contributing to slowness. try pagespeed in chrome that will provide improved/minified version of  javascript and css. hope that should help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that Firebug's 'Blocking' time actually the [time required to establish a connection with the server](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_Timeline). In the Firefox DevTools this is more obvious:

[image: 'Blocking' time in Firebug is actually connecting time]

And the connecting time may be influenced by several factors. In your case it looks like the images are blocked by the styles.css file, which takes extremely long to load regarding its size. I assume, this is caused by some proxy server or web application firewall or something else that may slow down the receiving of that file.